# On the history-of-science tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I recently got rid of the [history-of-science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-science) tag from [How far can history of science be traced back?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/how-far-can-history-of-science-be-traced-back), and then another question which had just been posted. Typically, I wouldn't do something like this, but it was a case where I felt that the tag was unnecessary.

My reasons for deleting it:

1. If a science question is on HSM, it is about the history of science (or on its way elsewhere).
2. There is already a [science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag (which I used to replace it on the first question, as it had been in use already).

Any thoughts on the issue? Should the tag be kept, or should it stay where it is - nowhere?

Comment: I completely agree. This tag seems completely redundant. It's like if math.se had a 'mathematics' tag.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to blacklist tags with the word "history" in it period. I expect this issue will be with our community for as long as that is not possible. Visitors will just continue to introduce the tag on occasion, and then while the tag is visible, it will continue to get used by other visitors until someone wipes the tag out again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you may already know, we already block the names of newly created sites from being used as tags on those sites. Removing [history-of-science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-science) from this site seems entirely in line with the spirit of that rule.

As J. W. Perry [pointed out](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235/on-the-history-of-science-tag/236#comment525_235), though, a lot of history tags are going to have the same issue. So, **we have just blacklisted all tags that begin with the word history**. For now, the system will still allow history to show up at not-the-beginning of a tag, but if this becomes a significant problem down the road, let us know and we can take another look.