# Blacklisted [history] tag has reappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Based on [this answer](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/236/58), [history] (as well as any other tag beginning with the word "history") is supposed to be a blacklisted tag on the main site. However that has apparently failed. This may not even be the first time it has failed as the tag was supposed to be blacklisted [6 months earlier](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/196/58) (at that time blocking anything even containing the word "history" rather than just beginning with that word) but for some reason the issue reappeared then and has reappeared again now.

[The tag](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) has showed up again and is now present on almost 50 questions. I am requesting:

- The tag be automatically removed from all posts; and
- Whatever issue caused the blacklist to fail to block this tag's creation and use is corrected.

Comment: Seems the tag was recreated on [Nov 16, 2019](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11158/5897). As a mod, check which patterns are currently blacklisted on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/admin/blocklist.

Comment: An August 2021 post about the same issue: [Those who do not know \[history\] are doomed to recreate it](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/9394)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is with the way the block was implemented (as site mods can verify on [this page](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/admin/blocklist), which lists all blocked tags and other blocked input for the site).

The regex for this particular tag-blocking seems to specifically check for a tag name consisting solely of `history-` followed by one or more "word characters" (i.e. alphanumeric characters or underscores).

So as written, something like `history-of` matches the regex (meaning [history-of](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) can't be created as a tag). But just `history` doesn't match the regex (since it doesn't have the hyphen or a word character after it), and neither does `history-of-science` (since it has at least one non-word character: the hyphen) – meaning it doesn't stop [history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) or [history-of-science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-science) from being (re)created as tags.

Blocklists need dev access to fix, so I've added the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to this post so that it can be escalated to the appropriate staff.

(Even after the tag blocklist entry is fixed, though, I think the tag will still need to be manually removed from the questions it's currently on.)

---

#### Update

The tag block has now been fixed. A dev has updated the regex for the blocklist to ensure that `history` will be blocked (i.e. can no longer be created as a tag), as well as anything beginning with the word `history` followed by any combination of dashes and alpha-numeric chars.

The tag still needs to be manually removed from the questions it's on (which I believe can be done by moderators or other users). Once this tag is "burninated", users should no longer be able to recreate it.